# A summation series of binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Given.

$$(1 + x^{2005} + x^{2006} + x^{2007})^{2008} = A_0 +A_1x +A_2x^2 + \cdots + A_nx^n$$

We are required to calculate $A_0 - A_1/3-A_2/3 + A_3 -A_4/4 -A_5/5 + A_6 - \cdots$

I tried approaching the problem by setting $x$ to 1 and $ω$ in two different cases.

For $x=1$, we get sum of all coefficients as $4^{2008} $

For $x=ω$ , we get :$-   (A_0 + A_3 +A_6 + \cdots) -\frac12(A_1+A_2+A_4+A_5+\cdots) =1$

(Since setting $x = ω$ in the given equation up top, we get LHS${}={}$RHS${}=1$, thus comparing the real parts we get the result)

But solving this two equations simultaneously gives me a wrong result.
Would appreciate if anyone could point out the mistake in my approach.

Comment: What do you mean by $x=\omega$. And, wouldn't you be interested in A0 - A1/1-A2/2 + A3 -A4/4 -A5/5 + A6 ......? I don't clearly see the pattern.

Comment: I see that $A_1=\ldots =A_{2004}=0$

Comment: I mean wriiting ω(imaginary cube root of unity) in place of x
no that is the pattern: A0 -A1/3 - A2/3 + A3 - A4/4 - A5/5 + A6 +...

Comment: $A_0-\frac{1}{2}A_1-\frac{1}{2}A_2+A_3-\frac{1}{2}A_4-\frac{1}{2}A_5+A_6+....=1$<br>$A_1-A_2+A_4-A_5+....=0$<br>$A_0+A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4.....=4^{2008}$But i could not find the value of the expression stated.Please help me find it.

Comment: I still don't see the pattern in the summation $A_0 - A_1/3-A_2/3 + A_3 -A_4/4 -A_5/5 + A_6 - \cdots$. Clearly, the coefficient of $A_n$ is $1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$, and when $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, the coefficient of $A_n$ is negative. But what is the pattern for those coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to represent the coefficients $A_k$ of the polynomial $A(x)$
\begin{align*}
A(x)=(1 + x^{2005} + x^{2006} + x^{2007})^{2008} = \sum_{j=0}^{2007\cdot2008}A_jx^j
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)&=(1 +x^{2005} + x^{2006} + x^{2007})^{2008}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2008}\binom{2008}{j}(x^{2005}+x^{2006}+x^{2007})^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2008}\binom{2008}{j}x^{2005j}(1+x+x^2)^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2008}\binom{2008}{j}x^{2005j}\sum_{{i_1+i_2+i_3=j}\atop{i_1,i_2,i_3\geq 0}}\binom{j}{i1,i2,i3}1^{i_1}x^{i_2}x^{2i_3}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{2008}\binom{2008}{j}\sum_{{i_1+i_2+i_3=j}\atop{i_1,i_2,i_3\geq 0}}\frac{j!}{i_1!i_2!i_3!}x^{2005j+i_2+2i_3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1)  we  use  the expansion with *[trinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion)*.

> Note, the polynomial $A(x)$ is sparse. If we write $A(x)$   in the form
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)&=(1 + x^{2005} + x^{2006} + x^{2007})^{2008}\\
> &=\binom{2008}{0}+\binom{2008}{1}x^{2005}(1+x+x^2)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\binom{2008}{2}x^{2005\cdot2}(1+x+x^2)^2\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\cdots\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\binom{2008}{2007}x^{2005\cdot 2007}(1+x+x^2)^{2007}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+x^{2005\cdot2008}(1+x+x^2)^{2008}
> \end{align*}
>
> we see that  the  expansion of $A(x)$ starts with
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(x)=1+2008x^{2005}+2008x^{2006}+2008x^{2007}+\frac{2008\cdot 2007}{2}x^{4010}+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   so,
>   \begin{align*}
> &A_1=A_2=\ldots=A_{2004}=0\\
> &A_{2008}=A_{2009}=\ldots A_{4009}=0
> \end{align*}

*Note:*  A pattern of the coefficients in OPs expression
\begin{align*}
A_0-\frac{1}{3}A_1-\frac{1}{3}A_2+A_3-\frac{1}{4}A_4-\frac{1}{5}A_5+A_6-\ldots
\end{align*}
is not obvious.